# Python Tkinter - Auto New Line + Auto Indent after {

Tags: python, tkinter

I’m currently making a Code Editor in Python 3.10 with the Tkinter library.

I saw that in VSCode, after typing a **{** and hitting the “*Enter*” key it automatically creates a new line and automatically indents your text (and adds the **}** at the end).

```
int main() {
    > …
)
```

I wonder if the same can be done also on Tkinter. Can someone show me how to implement it?

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font

def autoIndent():
    index = f"{textBox.index('insert')}-1l linestart"
    string = textBox.get(index, f"{index} lineend")

    tab_count = len(string) - len(string.lstrip("\t"))
    textBox.insert("insert linestart", "\t" * tab_count)


def completeCharacter(event):
    characterList = {
        '"': '"',
        "(": ")",
        "[": "]",
        "{": "}",
        "<": ">",
    }

    matching = characterList.get(event.char, None)
    if matching:
        event.widget.insert("insert", matching)
        event.widget.mark_set("insert", "insert-1c")

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1200x600")
root.title("Code Editor")

mainFrame = Frame(root)
mainFrame.pack(pady=0, fill="both", expand=True)

YScroll = Scrollbar(mainFrame)
YScroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
XScroll = Scrollbar(mainFrame, orient="horizontal")
XScroll.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

fontName = StringVar(root)
fontName.set("Consolas")
fontSize = StringVar(root)
fontSize.set("18")

wrap = StringVar(value='none')
textBox = Text(mainFrame, width=100, height=25, font=(fontName.get(), fontSize.get()),
               selectbackground="#FFFFBF", selectforeground="black", undo=True,
               yscrollcommand=YScroll.set, pady=10, padx=10, wrap=wrap.get(),
               xscrollcommand=XScroll.set)

textBox.bind("<Return>", lambda ev: textBox.after(1, autoIndent))
textBox.bind('<Key>', completeCharacter)

textBox.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

tabNumber = 4
textFont = font.Font(font=textBox['font'])
tab = textFont.measure(' ' * tabNumber)
textBox.config(tabs=tab)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: try implementing yourself and then come back and ask a question if you get stuck.

Comment: I can figure out how to say the character from the given dictionary equals to a {" in Python

Comment: Post you code.... so that I can run it and see what your doing wrong or what your next steps should be.

Comment: I edited the question and posted it.